# Ambiguity Regarding Spring Constructor Injection

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

why am i able to see First Constructor even if i specified the type can anyone please explain me what is happening behind the scene... since i don't want to specify the index positions i need to call second constructor based on the type.

```
public class Employee {


    String name;
    int id;
    public Employee(String name,int id) {
    System.out.println("First Constrcuot ");
    }

    public Employee(int id,String name){
        System.out.println("Second Constrcuot ");
    }
}
```

I have  My Beans.xml as follows:

```
<bean id="employee" class="com.test.di.Employee">
        <constructor-arg type="int">
            <value>10</value>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
            <value>100</value>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

Comment: You would have to specify the index as even with specifying the type both constructors would be considered a match. Both take an `int` and `String` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to specify exact data types for constructor args to avoid constructor injection type ambiguities. Refer [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/constructor-injection-type-ambiguities-in-spring/) example for more details

Can you try

```
<bean id="employee" class="com.test.di.Employee">
        <constructor-arg type="int">
            <value>10</value>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String">
            <value>100</value>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```