# Multiple Constructor injection ambiguity with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I am trying to learn to migrate one spring XML based application to spring boot application and wondering with one scenario where we have multiple constructors in a class and wish to inject all these using spring annotation.

I do understand and implemented the way using XML based configuration but confused with which annotation/way to inject multiple constructors.

I tried referring to few forums like : [Ambiguity Regarding Spring Constructor Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877399/ambiguity-regarding-spring-constructor-injection) but no luck with spring boot. 
Could anyone please help on this please?

Comment: An object can only be constructed once. Spring will only call one of your constructors: the one annotated with `@Autowired` (Or the only one if there is just one).

Comment: Like @JBNizet said, you can only use a single constructor. Can you tell us why you have these multiple constructors and why you're not using a single constructor? If we understand your use case, we might be able to provide a tailored answer.

Comment: I want to achieve similar thing in spring boot.  I want to call employee class with either of its  constructors.                                        
      <bean id="employee" class="com.test.di.Employee">
        <constructor-arg type="int">
            <value>10</value>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String">
            <value>100</value>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

Comment: Then use an `@Bean`- annotated method of one of your `@Configuration` class to construct the bean by yourself. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java-bean-annotation

Answer (score 1):

As it was mentioned in comments you can use `@Configuration`

```java
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public Employee employee() {
        return new Employee(10,"100");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @lczapski for the crisp code. Thanks JBNizet and g00glen00b for comments.